# Plot a gradient line on bar chart

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

Hi I have a question on how to plot a calculated gradient fit (fd4,fdata4) into a bar chart. 
Data 1 is the raw data, using `FindFit` function I got the gradient fit but I would like to plot the function into the bar chart? Any recommended steps that I can take note of?

```
Data1 = {10.95, 11.35, 10.0533, 10.22, 9.66, 10.2283, 10.3889, 10.8889,
    10.1667, 10.7111, 11.7917, 12.2083, 10.7667, 11.5417, 12.0583, 12.55,
    12.175, 12.9167, 14.4333, 14.9917, 14.7417, 14.9333, 15.8455, 15.95, 
    17.1773, 17.6, 13.9909, 14.0909, 14.7545, 14.6227, 15.8212, 15.5848, 
    15.2152, 14.8697, 13.8, 13.8333, 15.1472, 15.0861, 14.2111, 14.4639, 
    13.6583, 14.1194};

fd4 = FindFit[Data1, {a + b*x + c*x^2 + d*x^3 + e*x^4}, {a, b, c, d, e}, x]
```

> {a -> 12.1913, b -> -0.872446, c -> 0.10227, d -> -0.0033337, 
>        e -> 0.0000338078}

```
fdata4 = a + b*x + c*x^2 + d*x^3 + e*x^4 /. fd4
```

> 12.1913 - 0.872446 x + 0.10227 x^2 - 0.0033337 x^3 + 0.0000338078 x^4

```
label = {"5 S1A", "5 S1B", "5 S2A", "5 S2B", "5 S3A", "5 S3B", 
   "7 S1A", "7 S1B", "7 S2A", "7 S2B", "10YS1A", "10YS1B", "10YS2A", 
   "10YS2B", "10YS3A", "10YS3B", "10XS1A", "10XS1B", "10XS2A", 
   "10XS2B", "10XS3A", "10XS3B", "20YS1A", "20YS1B", "20YS2A", 
   "20YS2B", "20XS1A", "20XS1B", "20XS2A", "20XS2B", "27 S1A", 
   "27 S1B", "27 S2A", "27 S2B", "27 S3A", "27 S3B", "30 S1A", 
   "30 S1B", "30 S2A", "30 S2B", "30 S3A", "30 S3B"};

CombineBarchart = BarChart[{Data1}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  PlotLabel -> "Individual Resistance per Length Value at 0.2 Strain Condition ",
  AxesLabel -> {"Sample Length",  "(ΔkΩ/(n*cm)"}, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ label, Axis], 
  Frame -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the `Epilog -> {Black,Line@Table[{x, fdata4}, {x, 1, Length@Data1}]}` after your `PlotRange` definition
[image]

You can change the line style definition like usually in `Graphics`.

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** You can also use the option `Joined` with a function setting as follows:

```
BarChart[Data1, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
   PlotLabel -> " Individual Resistance per Length Value at 0.2 Strain Condition ",
   ChartLabels -> Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ label, Axis], 
   AxesLabel -> {"Sample Length", "(ΔkΩ/(n*cm)"},
   Joined -> {{Mean[#1[[1]]], fdata4 /. x -> Mean[#1[[1]]]} &}] /. 
 Line[x_] /; Length[x] > 2 :> {Red, Thick, Line[x]}
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
CombinedBarchart2 = BarChart[{Data1}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
   PlotLabel -> " Individual Resistance per Length Value at 0.2 Strain Condition ", 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ label, Axis],
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Opacity[0], Automatic}}, 
   PlotRange -> All];

Labeled[Show[CombinedBarchart2, 
    ListLinePlot[Table[fdata4, {x, 1, Length @ Data1}], PlotStyle -> Thick]], 
  {Style["Sample Length", 12, "Panel", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
   Rotate[Style["(ΔkΩ/(n*cm)", 12, "Panel", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 90 Degree]},
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try.